# Get data relative to current user

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a wishlist app. I want when the user goes on the wishlist page that the wishlists displayed are his own. I am using the SimpleMembershipProvider so I added a few properties to the AspNetUsers DB table such as the Wishlist field which is a foreign key to wishlist. How can I get the current users wishlist? I even created a User_Id foreign key field in the Wishlist object.

Answer (score 1):

You should have access to the user id through `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId`.

You can map a `User` entity to your users table, including references to your `Wishlist` table.  Or if you are using model first, have EF generate the `User` entity for you!

Then you can use `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` to load the current `User` entity from your database.

For example:

```
var user = _database.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
var wishlist = user.Wishlist;
```

---

**EDIT**

If not using `WebSecurity`, you could get the user name using:

`var username Membership.GetUser().UserName;`

Then you can access your `User` entity:

```
var user = _database.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == username);
var wishlist = user.Wishlist;
```

Comment: I am using the AspNetUsers table with my custom properties added. WebSecurity is not recognized. I'm on VS2013, .Net 4.5, EntityFramework v4.0.

Comment: Are you missing a using statement, perhaps?

Comment: @Chris, I have added an alternative method that doesn't require `WebSecurity`.

Comment: @Oliver: I am aware of that method. I guess I would have to stick the username in the DB? I would prefer an int id.